# Golang sqlc how to auto generate tables based on schema.sql file?

Tags: go, sqlc

I'm following this [tutorial](https://docs.sqlc.dev/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started-postgresql.html) using Golang sqlc with Postgresql, there is an error that says: `pq: relation "authors" does not exist exit status 1` whenever I run `go run main.go` after setting up everything. So the table "authors" is not being generated automatically, how does sqlc generate tables based on the schema.sql file? Do I have to manually copy and paste the code in schema.sql into DBMS SQL script for it to create tables?

Comment: I agree that the tutorial is a little unclear on this, but SQLC does not generate database tables for you.  For the purposes of the tutorial I'd suggest doing it manually, for larger apps consider the options [in the docs](https://docs.sqlc.dev/en/latest/howto/ddl.html?highlight=migration#handling-sql-migrations).

Comment: That's the whole point of the library isn't it? To work with your existing databases and SQL scripts you are using to create them.

Comment: @RichardHuxton SQLC generates Go code to access the tables (e.g. takes `SELECT * FROM authors
WHERE id = $1 LIMIT 1;` and generates a go function that runs that query for you, putting the results into a `struct` etc). It does not create the schema for you; managing migrations is left for other tools (as per [the docs](https://docs.sqlc.dev/en/latest/howto/ddl.html?highlight=migration#handling-sql-migrations)). [Here](https://github.com/kyleconroy/sqlc/tree/main/examples/authors/postgresql) is the full code generated in the tutorial.